# ajax laravel 5.5 post form returns 419 (unknown status) error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

i have a modal on my public page. from this modal at first i want the applicant to enter their email and after that i check if they have applied for tho job before or not. i want to do that with ajax so the whole page wont need to reload. 
this is my route:

```
Route::post('/candidate/checkemail', 'CandidatesController@checkEmail')->name('candidate.checkemail');
```

and this is how i handled it in the modal view:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                        <form >
                            <div class="form-group" >
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email1" name="email" placeholder="email"
                                       required>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" id="emailCheck" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit pull-left" onsubmit="checkEmail({{$jobpost->id}})">ثبت اطلاعات</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                    </div>

                </div>
```

i used script tag to define jquery function in the view:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({

        headers: {

            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

        }

    });



    $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',

            url:'/candidate/checkemail',
            data:{email:email},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.success);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

this view extends layoutes.app and i added fallowing to the header as i was told

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

but i get the error 419 (unknown status).